# How to call API from an Azure Powershell Runbook? Getting Error

Tags: azure-web-app-service, azure-logic-apps, azure-automation, azure-runbook

I'm trying to call an API within an Azure Automation Account by using a Powershell Runbook and I'm getting A 405 error when I attempt a GET method and a 499 eroror when I attempt a POST.

```
$uri = "https://xxxxxxxx-xxxxxxxx-prod-api.azurewebsites.net/api/PortfolioExport?PortfolioBatchDate=9/9/9999"
$tenantId = "xxxxxxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxx-7181039d1ed4"
$clientId = "xxxxxxxxxxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxx-5268b21e2920"
$clientSecret = "xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx~~U7n06yxQlc49"
$resource = "https://xxxxx.com/xxxxx.riskanalysis.app"

$tokenEndpoint = "https://login.microsoftonline.com/$tenantId/oauth2/token"
$body = @{
     grant_type = "client_credentials"
     client_id = $clientId
     client_secret = $clientSecret
     resource = $resource
     audience = $resource # Specify the audience parameter here
 }
 $response = Invoke-RestMethod -Method Post -Uri $tokenEndpoint -Body $body
 $accessToken = $response.access_token

 $headers = @{
     Authorization = "Bearer $accessToken"
 }

 Invoke-RestMethod -Method Get -Uri $uri -Headers $headers
```

This is the error that I receive when attempting to run the above code...

```
Invoke-RestMethod : The remote server returned an error: (405) Method Not Allowed.
At line:26 char:2
+  Invoke-RestMethod -Method Get -Uri $uri -Headers $headers
+  ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidOperation: (System.Net.HttpWebRequest:HttpWebRequest) [Invoke-RestMethod], WebExc
   eption
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : WebCmdletWebResponseException,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.InvokeRestMethodCommand
```

When attempting to use POST, Here is the message

```
Invoke-RestMethod : The remote server returned an error: (499).
```

At line:26 char:2

- Invoke-RestMethod -Method POST -Uri $uri -Headers $headers
- ```
   + CategoryInfo          : InvalidOperation: (System.Net.HttpWebRequest:HttpWebRequest) [Invoke-RestMethod], WebExc
  eption
   + FullyQualifiedErrorId : WebCmdletWebResponseException,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.InvokeRestMethodCommand
  ```

We have a Logic app that fails to run due to the timeout time which is why I'm trying to go the automation account route. This is the logic app JSON, which runs correctly but fails to complete. I tried using this code as reference for calling the API within the Runbook so maybe I didn't do it correctly.

```json
{
    "definition": {
        "$schema": "https://schema.management.azure.com/providers/Microsoft.Logic/schemas/2016-06-01/workflowdefinition.json#",
        "actions": {
            "HTTP": {
                "inputs": {
                    "authentication": {
                        "audience": "https://xxxxx.com/xxxxx.riskanalysis.app",
                        "clientId": "xxxxxxxxxxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxx-5268b21e2920",
                        "secret": "xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx~~U7n06yxQlc49",
                        "tenant": "xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx-7181039d1ed4",
                        "type": "ActiveDirectoryOAuth"
                    },
                    "method": "POST",
                    "uri": "https://xxxxxxxx-xxxxxxxx-prod-api.azurewebsites.net/api/PortfolioExport?PortfolioBatchDate=9/9/9999"
                },
                "limit": {
                    "timeout": "PT15M"
                },
                "runAfter": {},
                "type": "Http"
            }
        },
        "contentVersion": "1.0.0.0",
        "outputs": {},
        "parameters": {},
        "triggers": {
            "Recurrence": {
                "evaluatedRecurrence": {
                    "frequency": "Month",
                    "interval": 1,
                    "startTime": "2022-06-01T06:00:00Z",
                    "timeZone": "Central Standard Time"
                },
                "recurrence": {
                    "frequency": "Month",
                    "interval": 1,
                    "startTime": "2022-06-01T06:00:00Z",
                    "timeZone": "Central Standard Time"
                },
                "type": "Recurrence"
            }
        }
    },
    "parameters": {}
}
```

First part of the runbook that calls an sql stored procedure:

```
# Instantiate the connection to the SQL Database
$sqlConnection = new-object System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection
$sqlConnection.ConnectionString = "Data Source=xxxxxxxxxxx.database.windows.net;Initial Catalog=xxxxxxx;Integrated Security=False;User ID=xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx;Password=xxxxxxxxxxxx;Connect Timeout=60;Encrypt=False;TrustServerCertificate=False"
$sqlConnection.Open()
Write-Output "Azure SQL database connection opened"
# Define the SQL command to run
$sqlCommand = new-object System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand
$sqlCommand.CommandTimeout = 0
$sqlCommand.Connection = $sqlConnection
Write-Output "Issuing command to run stored procedure"
# Execute the SQL command
$sqlCommand.CommandText= 'DECLARE @ReportDate datetime; SET @ReportDate = GETDATE(); EXEC Reporting.PortfolioBuild2 @ReportDate'
$result = $sqlCommand.ExecuteNonQuery()
Write-Output "Stored procedure execution completed"
# Close the SQL connection
$sqlConnection.Close()
Write-Output "Run completed"
Write-Output "Run started"
# Instantiate the connection to the SQL Database
$sqlConnection = new-object System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection
$sqlConnection.ConnectionString = "Data Source=xxxxxxxxxxx.database.windows.net;Initial Catalog=xxxxxxx;Integrated Security=False;User ID=xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx;Password=xxxxxxxxxxxx;Connect Timeout=60;Encrypt=False;TrustServerCertificate=False"
$sqlConnection.Open()
Write-Output "Azure SQL database connection opened"
# Define the SQL command to run
$sqlCommand = new-object System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand
$sqlCommand.CommandTimeout = 0
$sqlCommand.Connection = $sqlConnection
Write-Output "Issuing command to run stored procedure"
# Execute the SQL command
$sqlCommand.CommandText= 'DECLARE @ReportDate datetime; SET @ReportDate = GETDATE(); EXEC Reporting.PortfolioBuild2 @ReportDate'
$result = $sqlCommand.ExecuteNonQuery()
Write-Output "Stored procedure execution completed"
# Close the SQL connection
$sqlConnection.Close()
Write-Output "Run completed"
Write-Output "Run started"
# Instantiate the connection to the SQL Database
$sqlConnection = new-object System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection
$sqlConnection.ConnectionString = "Data Source=xxxxxxxxxxx.database.windows.net;Initial Catalog=xxxxxxx;Integrated Security=False;User ID=xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx;Password=xxxxxxxxxxxx;Connect Timeout=60;Encrypt=False;TrustServerCertificate=False"
$sqlConnection.Open()
Write-Output "Azure SQL database connection opened"
# Define the SQL command to run
$sqlCommand = new-object System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand
$sqlCommand.CommandTimeout = 0
$sqlCommand.Connection = $sqlConnection
Write-Output "Issuing command to run stored procedure"
# Execute the SQL command
$sqlCommand.CommandText= 'DECLARE @ReportDate datetime; SET @ReportDate = GETDATE(); EXEC Reporting.PortfolioBuild2 @ReportDate'
$result = $sqlCommand.ExecuteNonQuery()
Write-Output "Stored procedure execution completed"
# Close the SQL connection
$sqlConnection.Close()
Write-Output "Run completed"
Write-Output "Run started"
# Instantiate the connection to the SQL Database
$sqlConnection = new-object System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection
$sqlConnection.ConnectionString = "Data Source=xxxxxxxxxxx.database.windows.net;Initial Catalog=xxxxxxx;Integrated Security=False;User ID=xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx;Password=xxxxxxxxxxxx;Connect Timeout=60;Encrypt=False;TrustServerCertificate=False"
$sqlConnection.Open()
Write-Output "Azure SQL database connection opened"
# Define the SQL command to run
$sqlCommand = new-object System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand
$sqlCommand.CommandTimeout = 0
$sqlCommand.Connection = $sqlConnection
Write-Output "Issuing command to run stored procedure"
# Execute the SQL command
$sqlCommand.CommandText= 'DECLARE @ReportDate datetime; SET @ReportDate = GETDATE(); EXEC Reporting.PortfolioBuild2 @ReportDate'
$result = $sqlCommand.ExecuteNonQuery()
Write-Output "Stored procedure execution completed"
# Close the SQL connection
$sqlConnection.Close()
Write-Output "Run completed"
```

Logic app code:

```
 "definition": {
     "$schema": "https://schema.management.azure.com/providers/Microsoft.Logic/schemas/2016-06-01/workflowdefinition.json#",
     "actions": {
         "HTTP": {
             "inputs": {
                 "authentication": {
                     "audience": "https://xxxxxxxxxxxxxx/xxxxxxxxxxxx.riskanalysis.app",
                     "clientId": "xxxxxxxxxxxxxxa-a2a5-5268b21e2920",
                     "secret": "xxxxxxxxxxxxxxweIkcS3qkq7~~U7n06yxQlc49",
                     "tenant": "xxxxxxxxxxxxxxx-a6a9-7181039d1ed4",
                     "type": "ActiveDirectoryOAuth"
                 },
                 "method": "POST",
                 "uri": "https://xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx-api.azurewebsites.net/api/PortfolioExport?PortfolioBatchDate=9/9/9999"
             },
             "limit": {
                 "timeout": "PT15M"
             },
             "runAfter": {},
             "type": "Http"
         }
     },
     "contentVersion": "1.0.0.0",
     "outputs": {},
     "parameters": {},
     "triggers": {
         "Recurrence": {
             "evaluatedRecurrence": {
                 "frequency": "Month",
                 "interval": 1,
                 "startTime": "2022-06-01T06:00:00Z",
                 "timeZone": "Central Standard Time"
             },
             "recurrence": {
                 "frequency": "Month",
                 "interval": 1,
                 "startTime": "2022-06-01T06:00:00Z",
                 "timeZone": "Central Standard Time"
             },
             "type": "Recurrence"
         }
     }
 },
 "parameters": {}
}
```

Comment: "The remote server returned an error: (405) Method Not Allowed,"  indicates that the HTTP method you're using (GET in this case) is not allowed by the server.

Comment: When I use Post....I get the following error: Invoke-RestMethod : The remote server returned an error: (499).
At line:26 char:2
+  Invoke-RestMethod -Method POST -Uri $uri -Headers $headers
+  ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidOperation: (System.Net.HttpWebRequest:HttpWebRequest) [Invoke-RestMethod], WebExc
   eption
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : WebCmdletWebResponseException,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.InvokeRestMethodCommand

Comment: I'm guessing that is a timeout of some sort. Is there a way to prevent the timeout from occurring if that is the case?

Comment: @MichaelShepard are you calling a function using its URL in logic app?

Comment: @IkhtesamAfrin I'm trying to convert 2 logic apps into a runbook because the time limit imposed by microsoft for logic apps. The first part calls an Azure SQL stored procedure which I've already done successfully. The 2nd part should call an API thats been created that does the conversion to an xlsx file.  The 2nd part is what i've been having trouble adding the runbook. SHould I split the runbook into 2 or should I just call the logic app that's already in place for the 2nd part?

Comment: @MichaelShepard please share the screenshot of both the workflows

Comment: @MichaelShepard please share your logic app design diagram

Comment: @IkhtesamAfrin I just added the runbook where I call the SQL stored procedure......And the logic app that I'm attempting to convert into a powershell script to add to the runbook after calling the stored procedure.